# How to automatically find out which assemblies should I reference and which namespaces should I be using?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, msdn

If I know a name of the class I need to use I know I can see the namespace and assembly name in MSDN, but that's cumbersome.

Can I (in Visual Studio) somehow automatically add references to all assemblies and all necessary `using` statements to be able to use all the classes and extension methods I'm trying to use in my `.cs` source file?

Comment: ReSharper [has this sort of functionality](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Coding_Assistance__Importing_Namespaces.html)

Answer (score 1):

For any namespaces you want to add to your using statements, right click on the class you have typed out and then click Resolve, and pick the namespace from the list (if there is more than 1 that matches the class).

Comment: But that only works if the reference has already been added to the project, no?

Comment: @phoog yes, there is no way to automatically add references. It would require that VS load all the framework libraries (at least the reflection versions) into memory and attempt to resolve types on the fly.

Comment: Yes.  I don't know of a way that will automatically add it to the References for the project

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is No, there is no way using VS to add namespace to without adding the assembly as reference 
but in case you added the assembly, the shortest way is to go to the class after typing it and click the small arrow ( or Ctrl+Space) and choose the name space you want to add